# How to disable or eject virtual sdcard by adb on emulator memu player 7

Tags: adb, external-sd, shell, android-emulator

I'm trying to unmount the sdcard or virtually eject it, because not allowing me to run an APK that is presenting an issue. After a deep research even with app developers, they told me that disabling the sdcard from the emulator would be possible. Tried manually, from the android interface as well on setting, storage, and there doesn't show up any external storage device. Then tried on ADB, and once I see the directories there is /mnt and also /sdcard. Tried alot of things after researching on internet like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu>adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell umount /mnt/sdcard/
.android_secure
failed: Permission denied

C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu>adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell umount /mnt/shell/e
mulated
failed: Device or resource busy

C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu>adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell umount /mnt/sdcard/

failed: Invalid argument

C:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu>adb -s 127.0.0.1:21503 shell umount /sdcard
failed: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Are you aware that `/sdcard` and the other aliases for this mount point is not the sdcard but simply the internal storage? The path name is just for historical reasons as in Android 2 this really was the sdcard. Therefore to me it seems like you are trying to reject the user data partition which is required by the emulator to work. So may be you should better describe your actual problem so we can try to find a different way to bypass it.